# Advantages/disadvantages of using multiple periods in a panel dataset

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I am using panel data with individual-level fixed effects (i.e. I have one observation per person per period, multiple periods, and am including a fixed effect on the individual to control for individual-level constant effects).

What are the advantages/disadvantages associated with increasing the number of periods included within the analysis? *(i.e. above and beyond two periods, which is obviously the minimum for fixed effects)*

[i'm aware that including more periods will probably reduce standard errors, but are there other considerations]

Comment: It seems you have in mind that a panel data implies one-time cross_section data. The panel data must have at least two periods of time. Further Standard error depends on generally the sample-size.If you are interested in mean estimate,the idea to increase no. of periods may be useful.

Comment: Please give an idea how it could be costrued as Fixed effects model.

Comment: @subhashc.davar - sorry, on re-reading, I could see how what i had written may be misconstrued - edited to make clearer

Comment: whether you are interested in data analysis or design of study? This may help a user of this site to answer your question easily.

Comment: what type of analysis of data you are siming at.